# clang-format weird indentation of array of structs in C++

Tags: c++, code-formatting, clang-format

I'm trying to use clang-format (in VS code) to format my C++ files and configure it to my preferred style. For an array of structs (for getopts) it is adding a load of extra spaces and messing up the brace wrapping:

I'll append my .clang-format at the end of this query

Here's the way I want my array to appear:

```
int main()
{
  const struct option longopts[]=
  {
    {"log-file", required_argument, 0, LOGFILE},
    {"log-level", required_argument, 0, LOGLEVEL},
    {nullptr, 0, nullptr, 0}
  };
}
```

Here's how it actually appears:

```
int main()
{
  const struct option longopts[] =
      {
          {"log-file", required_argument, 0, LOGFILE},
          {"log-level", required_argument, 0, LOGLEVEL},
          {nullptr, 0, nullptr, 0}};
}
```

My .clang-format file contains:

```
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
IndentWidth: 2
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: true
BinPackParameters: true
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass: true
  AfterControlStatement: true
  AfterEnum: true
  AfterFunction: true
  AfterNamespace: true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true
  AfterStruct: true
  AfterUnion: true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  BeforeCatch: true
  BeforeElse: true
  IndentBraces: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
  SplitEmptyRecord: false
  SplitEmptyNamespace: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon
ColumnLimit: 0
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
IndentCaseLabels: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: true
NamespaceIndentation: All
PointerAlignment: Right
SortIncludes: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeParens: Never
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false
SpacesInAngles: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
UseTab: Never
```

Any solutions welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that exactly what you want could be achived, but sometimes easiest way is to slighly modify the source file to help-up the clang-format utility. At first you need to add an `ContinuationIndentWidth: 2` option to your format file. Then add a comma after the last item in the array:

```
{nullptr, 0, nullptr, 0}, // <---
```

And finnaly move the first curly brace on the same line as array name. The resulting file will be like this:

```
int main()
{
  const struct option longopts[] = {
    {"log-file", required_argument, 0, LOGFILE},
    {"log-level", required_argument, 0, LOGLEVEL},
    {nullptr, 0, nullptr, 0},
  };
}
```

Running the clang-format will leave it as it is. Tested on clang-format from the LLVM snapshot build `LLVM-9.0.0-r351376-win64.exe`.

Comment: Thanks! As you say, not quite perfect because of where the opening brace ends up, but a lot better than it was!